# Encoding output from trusted sources such as AD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, security, xss

We've been having a debate at work recently about the merits of encoding output data from trusted sources such as an Active Directory. We have a web application that displays list of users that are queried from AD and allows them to be managed in various ways. The argument goes that if the data coming from the AD is not Html encoded, then it's possible to inject script and perform XSS style attacks against the site if you have access to the Domain Controller; for example by adding a script as the first name name of a AD user.

The two schools of thought (1 for not validating and 2 for validating) seem to be:

1. If you've got access to the DC, you can do a lot worse than inject code into a site which displays information you've already got access to. You could also just view the information directly. So why bother?
2. If you were a domain admin, you could craft this attack thus creating a backdoor which would enable you to get access to information even if you left the company.

I think the issue at hand is really a more generic one, do you need to guard against (and thus encode) output data from a trusted source, in addition to the common practice of guarding against malicious input.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to always do output encoding. You've tagged the question with MVC, so I assume your web application is an MVC one. If you're using Razor views, output is automatically encoded. More details [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx).